# NOC Code for Solution Engineer/Cloud Engineer 2173 or 2174?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, resident-permit, canada, express-entry

I am not sure whether my current duties match Canada's NOC code 2173 or 2174.

**2173: Software engineers and designers**

Software engineers and designers research, design, evaluate, integrate and maintain software applications, technical environments, operating systems, embedded software, information warehouses and telecommunications software.

**2174: Computer programmers and interactive media developers**

Computer programmers write, modify, integrate and test computer code for microcomputer and mainframe software applications, data processing applications, operating systems-level software and communications software.

Can someone help me?

Below are my roles and responsibilities:

- Design solution architecture diagram and create structured documentation based on inputs from Solution Specialist
- Provide an estimation of development tasks in line with Sprint/ Agile development to be fitted into a roadmap before development
- Use the relevant set of programming frameworks for frontend and backend development not limited to Django & Flask, Python/Java, Node
  Js/Express JS, React & Vue Js, PHP/HTML/CSS, SQL/MongoDB, etc
- Design and Deploy solution APIs using Google Cloud/ AWS for building data pipelines and server processing, data warehouse and storage
  optimization
- Maintain coding standards & build reusable code and libraries for future use
- Configure the alert system for the solutions for quick resolution of bugs triggered by system and user feedback and create cost monitoring
  dashboards
- Ensure the system is fail-safe against all unwanted intrusions and leaky firewalls and access is provided only to authorized users
- Build data science models using Cloud ML/ Python Notebooks for the solutions which require the implementation of AI/ML recipes
- Use GitLab/ CSR to host the developed codes/ scripts/ notebooks for further use
- Do extensive research on new technologies, tools and platforms, solution packages, frameworks built by Google/ Amazon/ third-party/open source that can be utilized for the solutions/POCs

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain what an NOC code is?

Comment: Can you tell us why you are unsure which code is most appropriate to your circumstances?

Comment: Official IRCC guidelines are confusing.
NOC 2173: [link]https://www23.statcan.gc.ca/imdb/p3VD.pl?Function=getVD&TVD=122372&CVD=122376&CPV=2173&CST=01012011&MLV=4&CLV=4
NOC 2174:[link]https://www23.statcan.gc.ca/imdb/p3VD.pl?Function=getVD&TVD=122372&CVD=122376&CPV=2174&CST=01012011&CLV=3&MLV=4